# Texture solid color instead of texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, image, color

Whenever I try to change my object texture and insert textures it doesn't work but instead puts a solid color. I am in rendered mode when doing these and have tried material mode but it still doesn't work. I tried using the Polygon add-on to add textures directly but doesn't work. I tried it with just a regular shape but still does the same thing. [image] [image] [image]  Also tried doing it manually: [image] [image] Don't know whats happening.

Comment: My guess is you need to UV unwrap your mesh.

Comment: Sorry for offcomment, but where can i get this HDRI? It looks awesome!
I also think, like Christopher said, you have to enter edit mode and select all the mesh with "A" and unwrap it

Comment: I'm quite sure @ChristopherBennett is correct here. The textures you have there look like they are texture images designed to use UV maps, not procedural textures. So if your object is not UV unwrapped, the texture is misplaced on the faces. Most likely this is not simply a solid color you see there, just one small part or even just a few pixels of the texture stretched across the object.

Comment: @EvripidisLalissidis this is the HDRI I used: https://polyhaven.com/a/cape_hill (Its free)

Comment: UV Unwrapping worked! thank you.